# Batch rename movie folder(s) to movie file inside of folder?

Tags: batch, shell-script, rename, files-folders

I would like to rename my movie folder names to match the movie file name inside the movie folder. The movie files have the right names but the folders do not.

I've found batch file rename options for renaming the file inside the folder to the folder name but I need to do just the opposite.

I have found this:

```
RENAME [drive:][path][directoryname1 | filename1] [directoryname2 | filename2]
```

Not sure if this would work? Also, not sure how to file in the paths, etc.

I am new to this and not sure how to do it. If someone could also give an example of it written out that would be great.

This batch file renamer would rename all folders in the movie folder to match the movie file names inside the folders.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use bash shell? Here is an example for mp4 movies in direct subdirectories of your present working directory.

```
for movie in */*.mp4
do
    dir="${movie%/*}"   # strips shortest suffix that starts with /
    name="${movie##*/}" # strips longest prefix that ends with /
    name="${name:: -4}" # strips last 4 characters (.mp4)
    mv "$dir" "$name"   # renames the directory (only for direct subdirs)
done
```

If you want to navigate through several parent directories, let us call them genres, you can enclose this as inner loop into an outer loop as follows:

```
for parent in /my/comedies /her/documentaries /his/movies/personal
do
    pushd "$parent"         # makes parent the current working directory
    for movie in */*.mp4    # loop over mp4 files in direct subdirs of parent
    do
        dir="${movie%/*}"   # strips shortest suffix that starts with /
        name="${movie##*/}" # strips longest prefix that ends with /
        name="${name:: -4}" # strips last 4 characters (.mp4)
        mv "$dir" "$name"   # renames the directory (only for direct subdirs)
    done
    popd                    # return to previous working directory
done
```

There are other ways do do this, but if you are not too well at home in bash, you might prefer not to tinker about with bash' variable syntax `${variable...}`. One obvious modification is to replace the first `*` in `*/*.mp4` with more complicated letter-and-wildcard patterns; in bash those are largely the same as they are in the classical windows command prompt, e.g. `*1987*/*.mp4` for all subdirectories with the text `1987` in them.

Comment: I did get bash shell setup on my pc. It took a little time but I got it going. I have it open now. My question now is that I have only curtain folders of my movie collection that I want to perform this in. How do I enter the folder address in the code above? These folders have collections in them and each subfolder needs to be renamed.

Comment: My movie collection is also on a Synology with my Videos folder redirected in Windows to the folder on my Synology. So, the address reflects this.

Comment: Also, do I just copy and past the entire code (when correctly formatted) into the bash shell?

Comment: A lot of questions. My code was just an example of how you could go about your task under the simple assumption of direct subdirectories. It seems that you are not very experienced in bash, so I would suggest not to thinker with the inner part of the loop. But you could enclose my code into an outer loop over the directories that have subdirectories with movies in. I will try and add that to my answer.

Comment: Yes, you can copy-paste to bash, line per line. If you copy-paste as a block, you'll have to remove all `# comment` parts.
As a rule you also have to be carefull not to paste `tab` codes in bash, because they tend to auto-complete to known commands, but the code elements on this website do not contain tabs, only spaces. (At least when I write them).